# Definição da Medalha Jornalista

Tags: suporte, medalhas

Qual a definição completa da [**Medalha: Jornalista**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/61/publicist) cuja definição dada pelo site é:

> Compartilhou um link para uma pergunta que foi visitada por 1000 endereços IP exclusivos. Esta medalha pode ser concedida várias vezes.

Pois não é explicado:

- Como o link deve ser compartilhado (se pode ser compartilhado por e-mail, divulgação no facebook ou postagens em outros sites);
- Se a pergunta deve ser de minha autoria;
- Se a visita à pergunta só seria computada por membros do site; e
- Como seria a forma de registro que indica que fui eu (usuário registrado autor da pergunta) que compartilhei o link da pergunta.

Comment: Sobre a forma de registro: quando você clica em "compartilhar" estando logado, o link é personalizado com uma identificação. Sobre os outros pontos, a regra é basicamente o que está na definição mesmo, sem essas especificidades.

Comment: Tem só um detalhe além do que disse o @Bacco: links clicados de dentro da própria rede Stack Exchange não contam para a medalha. Só contam cliquem em links gerados pelo "compartilhar" e originados de fora da rede, em qualquer outro site ou mesmo por acesso direto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando eu clico no link "compartilhar" desta pergunta, é isso que é gerado: "`http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2635/132`". Este 132 no final é o meu código de usuário aqui do SOpt.

Respondendo as suas perguntas:

> - Como o link deve ser compartilhado (se pode ser compartilhado por e-mail, divulgação no facebook ou postagens em outros sites);
> - Se a pergunta deve ser de minha autoria;
> - Se a visita à pergunta só seria computada por membros do site; e
> - Como seria a forma de registro que indica que fui eu (usuário registrado autor da pergunta) que compartilhei o link da pergunta.

Tudo se baseia no código do usuário que vai embutido na URL. Se alguém acessar "`http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2635/132`", contará como um acesso de um link compartilhado por mim. Se o link acessado for "`http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2635/11443`", contará como um acesso de um link compartilhado pelo autor desta pergunta. Se o link for apenas "`http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2635`", então o acesso não contará para ninguém.

Por fim, a pergunta não precisa ser de sua autoria e a visita é computada por acessos a esta URL independente de serem por membros do site, por usuários anônimos ou por robôs de busca e indexação de conteúdo (ex: Google) <sup><sup>(entretanto, estou bem incerto acerca deste ponto)</sup></sup>. Tal como o texto da medalha diz, o que conta são os endereços IP.

Há um detalhe, tal como explicado pelo bfavaretto em um comentário nesta pergunta: Links originados de dentro da própria rede Stack Exchange não contam.

<sup><sup>Me corrijam se eu estiver errado acerca de algum detalhe.</sup></sup>

Comment: Eu tenho uma dúvida. Se eu compartilhar uma resposta, por exemplo `http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2643/3117` isso conta como um acesso para o link da pergunta?

Comment: @Math Não sei, mas acho que sim.